# Adding another web part to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a sharepoint site and i have a number of lists which i would like to add web pages to,
my problem is that when i go to the edit page mode there is only one web part, the main zone so i can only add the pages one on top of the other
but i want to add two pages side by side' i need to add more zones (right,left etc).
is there a way to this without using the sharepoint designer? (i have problems with it since the sharepoint site is 2007 and the office i have is 2013 so i can only use the webpage for it)

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: WebParts can be added into a webpart zone. If you dont have webpartzone in the layout you cannot add.

Comment: at the moment i only have the main web part zone in my layout,
is there a way of adding more zones to the layout without using the designer?

Comment: I hope this helps! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34843/add-a-web-part-zone-to-my-newsfeed-page-via-powershell